# Pivot based on Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

How do I achieve this output

TableName: Test

```
Code      Description    
A          Apple   
B          Ball
C          Cat
```

Output: Query

```
Apple        Ball     Cat
A            B        C
```

Comment: why do you need something like this?

Comment: for gird purposes @m.antkowicz

Comment: @DreamerXD,Which DBMS are you using..?

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SQL server means use below PIVOT table :

```
CREATE TABLE #Table(Code VARCHAR(1), Description  VARCHAR(15) )

INSERT INTO #Table(Code , Description )
SELECT 'A','Apple' UNION ALL  
SELECT 'B','Ball' UNION ALL
SELECT 'C','Cat'

SELECT *
FROM 
(
  SELECT Code , Description
  FROM #Table
) A
PIVOT
(
   MAX(Code) FOR Description IN ([Apple],[Ball],[Cat])
)pvt
```

Edit : For dynamic pivot

```
DECLARE @DynamicString VARCHAR(MAX) = '' , @DynamicPvt VARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SELECT @DynamicString = 
(
  SELECT STUFF ((SELECT ',' + RTRIM(Description) FROM #Table FOR XML 
  PATH('')),1,1,'')
)

SET @DynamicPvt = 'SELECT * 
FROM 
(
   SELECT Code , Description FROM #Table
)A
PIVOT
(
  MAX(Code) FOR Description IN ('+@DynamicString+')
)
PVt'

EXEC (@DynamicPvt)
```

Comment: what if my code is not harcoded like Apple,Ball,Cat ?

Comment: @DreamerXD,Use dynamic pivot in your query.

Comment: how bro not familiar dynamic pivot